# Did I lose my files or are can I just not see them after installing Mint 20?

Tags: partition, chown

I have 2 HDD and I (maybe incorrectly) chose the format option when I installed the Mint 20. I was thinking that the files on the second HDD would be preserved. I can't see them after the upgrade. It looks like the used space in the partitions would indicate the files are still there. I've tried chown to take ownership, but it still doesn't show the files that were saved before the install.

```
df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           792M  1.5M  791M   1% /run
/dev/sda5       457G  9.6G  425G   3% /
tmpfs           3.9G   36M  3.9G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1       511M  4.0K  511M   1% /boot/efi
tmpfs           792M   36K  792M   1% /run/user/1000
/dev/sdb1       477M  2.3M  445M   1% /media/jonadmin/Documents
/dev/sdb2       916G   72M  869G   1% /media/jonadmin/Media
```

sdb is the second HDD.  There are 2 partitions on it (1 and 2).

Comment: Which one is the second hard drive? `/dev/sdb`?